# Как добавить настройки на страницу записи?

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим создан произвольный тип записи, и текстового редактора в этой записи не будет, т.е. при вызове `register_post_type` в атрибуте `supports` `editor` не выбран. Предполагается добавление своего кода html на отдельную страницу записи.
Как это сделать?
т.е. нужно добавить похожие настройки, добавляемые на отдельную страницу:

```
add_action('admin_menu', function(){
    add_menu_page( __('settings','locale'), __('Settings','locale'), 'manage_options', 'plugin-options', 'add_post_setting', '', "60.5" );
} );
```

только такие настройки нужно добавить на страницу отдельной записи произвольного типа, как это сделать?
т.е. предполагается добавить вместо текстового редактора форму, и сохранять данные из этой формы, Формы будет в виде таблицы

Comment: Настройки в админке предназначены для страниц админки, и вытащить их на вашу страницу - неправильная идея. Ведь по сути они представляют собой html-формы с сохранением в опции. Вам нужно сделать свои формы и сохранение введённых настроек в опции

Comment: @KAGG Design, `Вам нужно сделать свои формы и сохранение введённых настроек в опции`,  
ну а если мне нужны настройки для каждой записи отдельно?  
почему плохая идея?  Видел похожее в плагине `tablepress`, там создаётся тип записи "таблицы", и на отдельной странице таблицы есть куча настроек

Comment: мне нужна страница настроек не для всех записей вместе взятых, а настройки для каждой записи отдельно, т.е. настройки можно было бы реализовать с помощью произвольных полей, а мне нужна форма для каждой записи отдельно, чтобы можно было добавить html-код настроек на страницу записи нового типа

Comment: Ну и какие проблемы туда закинуть метабоксы